# Disable auto formatting in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc, text-formatting

Whenever I enter data in LibreOffice, may it be a date or a number, LO is formatting it as such instead of leaving it as text. That terribly annoys me because I want the text I enter to remain in that exact format.

What I've tried so far:

- Right-clicking and setting the formatting to "text" - Incredibly annoying
- Using the `'` at the beginning of the cell - Works-ish, but still not the best solution
- Unchecking everything under `Tools -> AutoCorrect Options`

I went through all the menus and preferences and customizazion options now but I could not find an option to disable each and every single auto-formatting feature that LO calc offers. Numbers, currencies, dates, times, URLs, text-align, ...

Whatever I enter in a cell shall stay that way unless I specifically say otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not disable it completely, but there are a few workarounds. I myself like the following most, here's the example for Excel (LibreOffice works almost the same way):

**Change the default format for current sheet**

- select all cells (Ctrl+A)
- set Text-Format to all cells (through the ribbon as shown in the screen shot or through the right-click/context menu etc.)

(please note: in the screenshot I haven't selected all cells, only the B-column)
[image]

**Alternative solution: Use a macro:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Me.Sheets
    sh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
Next

End Sub
```

**Alternative solution: Change the default format for all sheets**

- Select all sheet tabs (right-click a worksheet tab -> Select All Sheets option)
- clicking the leftmost top corner of one of the worksheets.
- Apply the text format

**Set as default for all new Excel files**

- Save the workbook as an Excel Template
- The "Save template" dialogue will offer the option "Set as default template" put in the check mark (if it doesn't give you this option save it  named Book.xltx in the XLStart folder)
- Note: even though the worksheets in the new workbook will use text, additional (new) worksheets might use the general format again, so you have to use the above macro on the new worksheet or do in manually

Comment: This seems to be the best solution so far, I'll mark it as accepted if there's no better answer by tomorrow.

Comment: @confetti there are a few other solutions, for example you could set this to default, but then it will be this way every time you start Excel. What are you're requirements?

Comment: Actually that would be perfect, how can I set this as default? I use excel mostly to manually create tables to later export it to SQL, so I never use formatting at all and only rarely calculations.

Comment: @confetti see my updated answer, does that help?

Comment: I got it! It was actually even easier. I took your advise and went to save it as template. The "Save template" dialog offered me the option "Set as default template". I ticked that and now whenever I open a completely new document it uses that template and every cell is plain text. This works even without the macro. I'll accept your answer, it'd be nice if you can add that information to the post.

Comment: @confetti which excel version are you using? I merged my original answer with your "new option", did I do it right from you're point of view?

Comment: Maybe that's only for openoffice? I'm using libreoffice (openoffice based) 6.0.5.2. I'd say your answer reflects both cases very well now! Thank you a lot.

Comment: @confetti no problem, as I advised you on you're other question I think you should be more specific in you're question. (you can still ask for all version but at least you should mention you're software/version and describe what you need answers for excel as well - I found it rather confusing this way)

Answer (score 0):

I was tussling with this in Calc.  I copied a table from a web page and pasted it into Calc, and cell content that resembled a date was converted into a date, and because Calc transforms said data into a number, before formatting it into a date, the original intelligence is lost--thus, Format Cell to "Text" yields a text version of that number--NOT what I needed!.  When I say "All intelligence is lost", that's not entirely correct.  It still exists in the date.  It just needs to be trimmed out, and reformatted.

Example: Several of the columns on the web page had this format: n/m
e.g. 1/1, 2/4, 3/3, etc.  Calc would turn these into 01/01/23, 02/04/23, 03/03/23, respectively.  E.g. 0n/0m/23.

To address this, I sought assistance from ChatGPT and got the following formula that I used to affect this workaround:

1. Enter the following formula in an empty cell beneath the table,
   adjusting the cell references as necessary:

   ```
   =MONTH(A1) & "/" & DAY(A1)
   ```

   For example, it may become:

   ```
   =MONTH($F2) & "/" & DAY($F2)
   ```
2. Drag the fill handle (a small square in the lower right corner of
   the selected cell) to copy the formula down into the empty cells
   below. This action auto-fills the formula into the corresponding
   cells, adjusting the cell references automatically based on Calc
   rules.
3. Highlight and "cut" (copy and remove) all of these cells (the entire
   column).
4. Return to the table and click on the top cell of the column you want
   to fix.
5. Use the shortcut <Ctrl><Shift><V> (or the equivalent in
   macOS/Linux) to paste the values only. In the pop-up, select "Values
   Only" and confirm with "Yes" if prompted.

Voila! All the cells should now display the correct values. Finally, trim any cells that extend below the table using the <Ctrl><-> shortcut.

I realize that's nothing more than a kludgy workaround, but in the absence of anything else...